# When does the angle matters in Work laws?

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws

i've got this problem :
A 30.0-kg crate is initially moving with a velocity that has magnitude 3.90 m/s in a direction 37.0⁰ west of north. How much work must be done on the crate to change its velocity to 5.62 m/s in a direction 63.0⁰ south of east?
i've managed to find the work which is 246J according to the book by using W= E(final)- E(initial)
but my question is why have we not consider the angle her which is 170 degree ? When do we take the angle into consideration and when do we not have to ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The angle is not important as $|\vec{V}|^2$ is a scalar. The question is the net work on the object, which is only dependant on the final magnitude of velocity.

However to change the velocity from different angles, does initially require more/less work during the proccess dependant on the angles. However the FINAL net work. Is only dependant on the initial and final Ke

Imagine a scenario, where something is moving at some ke, north. To make that object move with the same ke south, would require 0 work, as the ke is the same. That is not to say, that each work element f.dr is 0, negative and positive work is being done such that the NET is zero

Answer (score 0):

Angle plays no part here as kinetic energy is a scalar. A body moving with a certain speed towards the east has the same kinetic energy as a body with an equal mass and speed moving towards the west. Since the work done is equal to the change in kinetic energy, and kinetic energy is angle-independent, the work done in this case is angle-independent too. However, if you want to use $W=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{s}$, the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{s}$ should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

> When does the angle matters in Work laws?

The only angle that matters in calculating work is the angle between the net force $\vec F$ and the displacement $d\vec s$ of the object. That's because the work done between two points is defined as

$$W=\int_1^2\vec F(x).d\vec s$$

In your example you don't need to know the angle, the net force, or how they may vary between the initial and final position because, per the work energy theorem, the net work done between two points on the object only depends on its change in kinetic energy between the points.

Hope this helps